# How to construct a dynamic (UI controls determined by db) XAML page?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to solve the following problem. In my XF app I have a page that has to be of a dynamic nature - the controls that will be rendered on the page (for each category "Location", "Gender") is determined from a database table.

[image: Screen mockup]

The database table has a similar schema:

[image]

How do I achieve that page design in a "nicer" way with as little C# as possible (primarily XAML)? I am looking for any suggestions and ideas.

Comment: I don't think there is an "easy" way to do this that doesn't involve a lot of C#.  You could define each Type of control in a XAML ContentView and use those blocks to build your UI, but it will still require C# to parse the UI definition and build the layouts.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I agree that the  problem cannot be solved without any C#.  I like your suggestion, I will try creating a XAML ContentView for each control and see how it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple solution for that. 
I have done something similar, though it required a lot of code, which even can't be simply  copy/pasted.

However I will try to give you a brief overview on how my solution looked like.

If I see it right, you want to have a TabbedPage with dynamic subpages being generated from a data source.

**1) Models**
You will need some sort of factory class, which will take your data and build some UIElementModels from it.
These models should describe your UI in an abstract way, so that they contain all the information for the UI Element that you want to use, e.g. the displayed text and the actual value.

```
public class UIElementModel
{
    public object ElementValue {get;set;}
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

Then derive improved models for the particular elements

```
public class UIButtonModel : UIElementModel
{
    public Command ClickAction {get;set;}
}

public class UIEntryModel : UIElementModel
{
    public string Placeholder {get;set;}
}

public class UIPickerModel : UIElementModel
{
    public List<string> Items {get;set;}
}
```

and so on. Feel free to add what ever you need to define content and visuals of your element to display.

**2) Elements and Pages**

Next you have to create custom UI elements deriving from the base UI Elements.
So for example, if you have a button, create a DynamicButton class which will accept a UIButtonModel as a binding context. I would also recommend of providing a constructor in which you can hand over such a model.

Then you create a DynamicPage deriving from a ContentPage, which will accept a List in its constructor.
When you create new instance of this page, you can programatically iterate through the List of the ui models, create an instance of the related custom ui element and put it into the page:

Pseudocode:

```
public DynamicPage(List<UIElementModel> uiElements) : ContentPage
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (UIElementModel model in uiElements)
    {
        if (model.Type == UIEntryModel)
        {
            DynamicEntry entry = new DynamicEntry(model);
            this.ElementStackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
        }
        if (model.Type == UIButtonModel)
        {
            DynamicButton button = new DynamicButton(model);
            this.ElementStackLayout.Children.Add(button );
        }
        ...
        // add more elements as needed
    }
}
```

once you have created your screens, you can put them into a TabbedPage and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer! That most certainly helps, I will be giving this approach a go.